# RTL8188ee WiFi very slow

Tags: iwlwifi, nic, rtl8723be, rtl, rtl8192ce

I recently bought a tp-link Archer wn781nd for my desktop.
The WiFi speed is very slow compared to my laptop.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.13.0 -41

I had a similar problem when using my laptop with rtl8723be which was solved by using the lwfinger drivers.

Comment: First, just from logic " I have tried every possible solution on the internet" is not correct. Seond, what's your `MTU`? `ifconfig` will show you. WiFi `MTU` should be `1492`, not `1500`

Comment: Ok edited MTU is 1500

Comment: @waltinator MTU is 1500

Comment: Because your `MTU` is 1500, data may buffered until 1500 bytes are accuimulated, then sent (at the network level). Once the 8 bytes of WiFi overhead are added, you have 1508 bytes of data. 1508 bytes of data must be sent in two packets, doubling the overhead. Replace `wlan0` with your WiFi interface name and do `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down;sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1492;sudo ifconfig wlan0 up;ifconfig wlan0` and chech that your `MTU` is changed. It might be reset to 1500 by your DHCP, but that's a different problem.

Comment: @waltinator changed the MTU but speed doesn't increase